# AFNetworking 2.0 JSON Parse

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

Here is my code.

```
(void)performHttpRequestWithURL :(NSString *)urlString :(NSMutableArray *)resultArray completion:(void (^)(NSArray *results, NSError *error))completion
{
    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:myUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
         NSLog(@"请求完成");
         NSArray *arr;
         arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:operation.responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:NULL];
         [resultArray addObjectsFromArray:arr];
         if (completion) {
             completion(resultArray, nil);
         }
    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
         NSLog(@"请求失败: %@", error);
         if (completion) {
             completion(nil, error);
         }
    }];
    [operation start];
 }
```

I can only use apple json parse, I don't know how to use AFNetworking json parse itself.
I didn't find AFJsonrequestOperaton in AFNetworking 2.0.ask for help, thank you.

Comment: Did you read the AFNetworking documentation? https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#afhttprequestoperation

Comment: What is your problem ? I am not seeing a question here. Is it that you can't find the AFNetwork JSONRequest ?

Comment: hey i have just posted and answer with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do it manually, just set the response serializer to JSON like this:

```
....
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

and now inside your block, `responseObject` should be the deserialised object (`NSDictionary` or `NSArray` depending on your root JSON object from the response)

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"Hooray, we got %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
     NSLog(@"Oops, something went wrong: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 2):

For AFNetworking 2.0 below sample code works:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


 NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"UserId": @"24",@"Name":@"Robin"};

NSLog(@"%@",parameters);
parameters = nil; // set to nil for the example to work else you can pass data as usual

// if you want to sent parameters you can use above code 

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


 }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: this code snippet is unclear. Can you add more explanation?